# MongoDB calculate count on date grouping

Tags: mongodb, date, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to calculate the allotment count of each day, by using **day** grouping on **assigned_on** I am able to get assignment count of each day, but those are unique count of each day.

In that count I also want that bed to be included which was assigned yesterday or few days before but not yet released.

For example, I have following records

```
{
    "assigned_on":ISODate("2015-12-01T00:00:00Z"),
    "released_on":ISODate("2015-12-01T14:01:23Z"),
    "bed_id":1
},

{
    "assigned_on":ISODate("2015-12-01T00:00:00Z"),
    "released_on":ISODate("2015-12-04T14:01:23Z"),
    "bed_id":2
},

{
    "assigned_on":ISODate("2015-12-01T00:00:00Z"),
    "released_on":ISODate("2015-12-01T14:01:23Z"),
    "bed_id":3
},

{
    "assigned_on":ISODate("2015-12-02T00:00:00Z"),
    "released_on":ISODate("2015-12-02T14:01:23Z"),
    "bed_id":1
},


{
    "assigned_on":ISODate("2015-12-02T00:00:00Z"),
    "released_on":ISODate("2015-12-02T14:01:23Z"),
    "bed_id":3
},

{
    "assigned_on":ISODate("2015-12-03T00:00:00Z"),
    "released_on":ISODate("2015-12-03T14:01:23Z"),
    "bed_id":1
},


{
    "assigned_on":ISODate("2015-12-03T00:00:00Z"),
    "released_on":ISODate("2015-12-03T14:01:23Z"),
    "bed_id":3
}
```

Current query

```
 db.test.aggregate([
      {
        "$match": {
          "assigned_on": {
            "$gte": ISODate("2015-12-01T00:00:00Z"),
            "$lt": ISODate("2015-12-03T23:59:59Z")
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "$group": {
          "_id": {
            "$dayOfMonth": "$assigned_on"
          },
          "Count": {
            "$sum": 1
          }
        }
      }
    ])
```

As by **day** grouping on assigned_on I get above result for day 1, 2 and 3, but I want to the Count for day 1, 2 and 3 as 3 for each in result because in second record the **released_on date is 4th december which means that bed 2 was occupied on day 1, 2, 3 and 4.**

Current output :

```
{ "_id" : 3, "Count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : 2, "Count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : 1, "Count" : 3 }
```

Expected output :

```
{ "_id" : 3, "Count" : 3 }
{ "_id" : 2, "Count" : 3 }
{ "_id" : 1, "Count" : 3 }
```

**Edit : The _id are the dates that is 1st December, 2nd December and 3rd December and count are the number of beds allotted on respective days**

An help or pointer will be very helpful

Comment: Your question is hard to understand

Comment: If you observe my sample data the record for bed 2 shows assigned_on as 1st December and released_on as 4th December, so that means the bed was occupied on 1st, 2nd , 3rd and 4th December as well . Currently I am able to get count for each day like you can see in result 1st Dec count is 3, 2nd Dec count is 2, 3rd Dec count is 2. But instead I want output as 1st Dec count 3, 2nd Dec count 3, 3rd Dec count 3, as bed 2 is occupied for 4 days i.e 1,2,3 and 4. Is it clear now ?

Comment: Can you please post what your expected output is? I really don't understand what you're trying to do

Comment: David I have added it

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with the mongodb [`mapReduce`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/core/map-reduce/):

```
var map = function(){

    var startDate = new Date(this.assigned_on.getTime());
    //set time to midnight
    startDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);

    //foreach date in date range [assigned_on, released_on) emit date with value(count) 1 
    for (var date = startDate; date < this.released_on; date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1)) {
        if(this.bed_id) {
            emit(date, 1);
        }
    }
};

//calculate total count foreach emitted date(key) 
var reduce = function(key, values){
    return Array.sum(values)
};

db.collection.mapReduce(map, reduce, {out : {inline : 1}}, callback);
```

For your data I got such result:

```
[ { _id: Tue Dec 01 2015 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (EET), value: 3 },
  { _id: Wed Dec 02 2015 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (EET), value: 3 },
  { _id: Thu Dec 03 2015 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (EET), value: 3 },
  { _id: Fri Dec 04 2015 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (EET), value: 1 } ]
```